# For each value in field A, select the row with some special value in field B, while respecting further criteria

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, greatest-n-per-group

**Disclaimer:** While the basis of my question—the *greatest-n-per-group* question—has been asked and also answered so many times before, I am facing a seemingly hard issue due to extra conditions that I have to apply.

In case I really missed the answer to my exact question that was given somewhere, I am sorry. I searched, read, tried, a lot, and I spent already half my day on this.

---

I tried to describe the **abstract problem** in the title: for any other field A value, get the row with some *special* field B value, and at the same time, respect further conditions.

Now, my **concrete problem** is as follows...
I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdl_datasets` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cmid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timecreated` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**For each user** (i.e., `userid`) in **one specific module** (i.e., `cmid`), I want to get the **most recent row** (i.e., maximum `timecreated`), **before a given timestamp** (i.e., again `timecreated`). The latter part makes it hard.

I don't see how I can do this without using at least three (sub)queries, and even then I'm unable to make it work properly in any case.

So far, I only managed to get it **partially** working, for example, only for users with at least two rows. This is wrong, of course. If there is a user with only a single row, which has a correct `timecreated` value, then I want to get this row as a result. For any other user, I want to get the one row with the greatest `timecreated` value that is below the given maximum date (as Unix epoch timestamp).

Is there anything else that I should mention? Tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is exactly the same case of the `max-per-group` but with some extended conditions and can be solved by single subquery:

```
SELECT IF( b.id IS NULL, NULL, a.id ) AS id -- an opposite to COALESCE()
     , a.cmid
     , a.userid
     , b.maxts -- can be NULL 
  FROM table AS a 
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id -- if you need no rows for users have no rows before 
                        -- the given timestamp replace the LEFT JOIN 
                        -- by plain JOIN
                   , cmid
                   , userid
                   , MAX(timecreated) AS maxts
                FROM table 
               WHERE cmid = given_cmid
                 AND timecreated < given_timecreated -- additional condition
               GROUP BY userid
            ) AS b ON b.userid = a.userid
                  AND b.cmid   = a.cmid
                  AND b.maxts  = a.timecreated
  WHERE a.cmid = given_cmid
;
```

This query produce the result for each `userid` in the table including those having no rows before the `given_timecreated` but with `maxts`, `id` and `cmid` set to the `NULL`.

Here condition `WHERE cmid = given_cmid` is used twice to reduce the size of the subquery result.

Sure you need an index `(cmid, userid, timecreated)` for acceptable performance. The order columns listed in the index can be different according to the specific data you have.

Comment: Thank you! That looks ... exotic. :) Right now, I get an error for the `IFNULL` because of too many parameters...? I am using MySQL (5.6). This function seems to only have two arguments?

Comment: @tfrommen Yes I mean `IF(c,y,n)` function

Comment: Thank you! I think this is working nicely. I'm looking into index optimization with `EXPLAIN`. Oh, and I also have to see if I'm able to make Moodle understand/do this. :)

Comment: @tfrommen As of my experience with Moodle it's too risky to change any part of its data by hand. It can be lookin quite successful until some day.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
select user_id,   max(timecreated) from mdl_datasets 
where  cmid=yourmoduleid and timecreated < yourtime
group by user_id ;
```

Max will return the very last row before "yourtime", for each user. 
This works for postgresql, but i am not very sure for mysql, because group by of mysql sometimes actcs like distinct on (column) in postgresql that will bring any row without any criteria for the other columns (because that postgresql, will reject group by with columns out of it if you dont specify the criteria (like max or something)) - but i think because of max mysql will understand the exactly row we want for each user as postgresql does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid this doesn't work, though, because I need the whole row, not just the user ID (which is the criteria for the `GROUP BY`) and the time. When I add `id` to the fields, I don't get the correct ID, but (like MySQL does), an arbitrary one. Ideas?

Comment: And if you run exactly the query  i answered you get the right id? so then you can use it on a subquery?

Comment: Are yout sayng that the query in my answers is getting any id without the respect for max?

Comment: Hm, yes, but I mean the ID for the row (i.e., `id`, not `userid`). I have the query like so `SELECT id, userid, MAX(timecreated)  FROM mdl_datasets ...`. Mind the `id` that I added. And the row that I get does not have the correct `id` (for the row with the maximum `timecreated`) but some other one (in my case the latest/highest).

Comment: Here is a Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1c90c/3 With the time provided, it works (but just because of the data that I put in there, so it's by coincidence). If you run the query without the timestamp (like it is now, with the commented out code), the result for `userid=3` is `id=23`, which is wrong. It should be `id=26`, as this is the row with the higher `timecreated` value.

Comment: I edited the question can you try again?

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't working though, as the ID is not the correct criterion. The timestamp does not necessarily increase with increasing ID (because it is nothing live that is being logged, but data/events) that are written to the database asynchronously, whenever it makes sense. The (complex-looking) query by @Kondybas is working great. Thanks anyway, really!